# RDS Free Storage for Maria DB is tanking after upgrading engine from 10.2 to 10.6

Tags: mariadb, amazon-rds

I recently upgraded my database engine on RDS from Maria 10.2 to 10.6. Since I've done that, I've noticed that the available free storage is dropping extremely quickly... way more quickly than what data writes account for.

I've checked user database info, logs, and all other metrics on RDS look normal. The site itself is a bit peppier than it was before the upgrade, so I checked the caching variables, and all seems to be normal there. Nothing I see accounts for a 10GB drop in free storage over the past 36 hours.

Any ideas?

[Image of Free Storage metric. The drop in the middle occurred during the upgrade.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/342XF.png)

Comment: This appear to be [MDEV-29192](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-29192), [MDEV-26782](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26782) and/or [MDEV-28240](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28240) which should be fixed in the next release. I don't know if [default_tmp_storage_engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#default_tmp_storage_engine) or [aria_used_for_temp_tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aria-system-variables/#aria_used_for_temp_tables) is available on RDS.

Comment: Apart from a rapid deployment of a bunch of application changes to avoid temporary tables I can't see an obvious workround until the next 10.6.10 deployment into RDS. I'd look at reverting to a < 10.5 version based on the bug reports examined.

Comment: @danblack THANK YOU for the explanation!  I will look at reverting it to 10.5 and look into the resources you provided. This gives us something to sink our teeth into and will post an update.

Comment: I also had some nice words with Thiru who jumped at implementing [MDEV-29479](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-29479) the visibility of innodb temporary table space information in `information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES` coming next release (in all released versions).